# How to create a BaseAction for Struts 1?

Tags: action, struts1, struts-action

I have this problem:

I need to create a BaseAction for a java web application (with Struts 1). 
All the actions will extend this BaseAction and all the actions have more methods (create, update, delete, list, etc). There's no "execute" method.

I need this in order to get the ApplicationContext for spring but also for authentication or other things that all actions should do.

When there's only "execute" method the things are easy...just create the BaseAction with "execute" method and an abstract "performTask" method. The "forward" will be the result of the "performTask" method that all other actions will implement.

So I can't do the same design for actions that have more than one method and every method has its own forward.

Thanx,
Adri108

Comment: I'm no Struts1 user but I've used Struts2 and other Java MVC frameworks and I fail to see where is the problem...

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the existing Spring integration where actions are normal Spring beans?

Comment: Now the application is already made without spring and is very difficult to modify. I'm trying to duplicate it and to make some tests, for example add spring just for some actions to see how it works. However, I would like to add the BaseAction also without spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Struts 1, `struts-config.xml` is a driving file. This file redirects various actions to respective `ActionForward` method.